# CSS and Javascript. Need make a div blink

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I need to make a div blink, and code below works when I execute it in develop mode. But when the code is executing in real time, it doesn't work. Why?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qED7k/) that doesn't work but has all the code.

All the code is javascript:

```
var jogo = {
    i : 0,
    pintado : new Array(),
    click : -1,
    momento: 0,
    rolando : false,

    sleep: function(milissegundos){
        var iniciar = new Date().getTime();
        for(var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++){
            if((new Date().getTime() - iniciar) > milissegundos){
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
}

function position(){
    var theight = $(window).height();
    var twidth = $(window).width();
    var cheight = $('#por2').height();
    var cwidth = $('#por2').width();

    var margint = (theight - cheight)/2;
    var marginl = (twidth - cwidth)/2;

    $('#por2').css('margin-top', margint);
    $('#por2').css('margin-left', marginl);

    var bwidth = $('#jogar').width();
    var bmarginl = (twidth - bwidth)/2;
    $('#jogar').css('margin-left', bmarginl);
}

function pintar(){
    var random = 0;

        while(random <= 0){ //RANDOMIZA UM NÚMERO PARA PINTAR UMA BOLINHA
            random = Math.floor((Math.random()*5));
        }

        if(jogo.rolando){ // CASO O JOGO JÁ ESTEJA EM ANDAMENTO
            var aux = 0;
            while(jogo.pintado.length > aux){ 
                //PINTA AS BOLAS QUE JÁ FORAM PINTADAS ANTES
                switch(jogo.pintado[aux]){
                    case 1:
                        $('#1').css('background','rgb(255,0,0)');
                        jogo.sleep(500);
                        $('#1').css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                    break;    

                    case 2:
                        $('#2').css('background','rgb(0,255,0)');
                        jogo.sleep(500);
                        $('#2').css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        $('#3').css('background','rgb(0,0,255)');
                        jogo.sleep(500);
                        $('#3').css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                    break;

                    case 4:
                        $('#4').css('background','rgb(255,255,255)');
                        jogo.sleep(500);
                        $('#4').css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                    break;
                }
                aux++;
            }

            // PINTA UMA BOLA COMO SE FOSSE A PRIMEIRA
            // AÇÃO PORÉM INCREMENTA O JOGO.I
            setTimeout(function(){
                switch(random){
                    case 1:
                        $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(255,0,0)');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                        },200);
                        jogo.i++;
                        jogo.pintado[jogo.i] = random;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(0,255,0)');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                        },200);
                        jogo.i++;
                        jogo.pintado[jogo.i] = random;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(0,0,255)');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                        },200);
                        jogo.i++;
                        jogo.pintado[jogo.i] = random;
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(255,255,255)');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                        },200);
                        jogo.i++;
                        jogo.pintado[jogo.i] = random;
                    break;
                }
            },400);
        }

        if(!jogo.rolando){ //CASO SEJA A PRIMEIRA VEZ DO JOGO
            switch(random){
            case 1:
                $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(255,0,0)');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                },200);
            break;
            case 2:
                $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(0,255,0)');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                },200);
            break;
            case 3:
                $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(0,0,255)');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                },200);
            break;
            case 4:
                $('#'+random).css('background','rgb(255,255,255)');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#'+random).css('background', 'rgb(10,10,10)');
                },200);
            break;
            }
            jogo.rolando = true;
            jogo.pintado[jogo.i] = random;
        }

        jogo.click = -1;    
}

function clicar(valor){
    jogo.click++;
    if(jogo.pintado[jogo.click] == valor){
        if(jogo.i == jogo.click){
            pintar();
        }
    }else{
        alert('perdeu');
    }    
}
```

Comment: What happens in *real time*? Any specific error/behaviour?

Comment: In real time, the div just don't change its color

Comment: What is the purpose of `jogo.sleep`

Comment: my guess is you are missing the library such as jquery

Comment: Out-of-Context: There was a reason to make the `<blink>` element as *non-standard and deprecated* from HTML !

Comment: Better create a jsfiddle

Comment: I'm trying to make a Genius game with JS :D this is the reason to make the div blink

Comment: My game didn't work in JSFiddle

Comment: Use `css transition` for `background-color` property.

Comment: I can't do it Pinal. I need a function who tell when to do it

Comment: @abhitalks: They didn't "make" the <blink> tag non-standard or "deprecate" it. It was never in any HTML standard in the first place.

Comment: You've added a fiddle. Can you provide instructions of what to press to make something blink?

Comment: It doesn't work in Fiddle, but if you want to test in your browser it'll be good. You'll need press the button green. Jogar equals Play.

Comment: Can you provide instructions of what should happen? The green button is pressed, then what should blink?

Comment: So we've the four balls, some of them need to blink. I've a random() to choose one.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ow. I used to think it was part of html and then removed. thanks for correction. And I picked the text from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your class jogo do, but in JavaScript there is complicated to do a sleep. So i recommend to use a callback, something like that:

```
$("#1").animate({
    background: "rgb(255,0,0)"}, 500, function(){
     $("#1").animate({background: "rgb(10,10,10)"}, 500);
    }
);
```

Comment: won't that flash not blink? blink is a recurring event.

Comment: Jogo is an Object. And sleep is a normal function of sleep. I'll try it

Comment: Almost, Have you ever played Genius? So I'm trying to make the div blink like that.

Comment: Try with this examples: http://www.jqueryanimate.net/jquery-animate-background-color.html . You need jQueryUI to do color animations.